# Включение AlarmManager в определенные дни недели

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-alarm-manager

Есть будильник:

```
    medication.get(i).setpI(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Medication.this, medication.get(i).getUnique(), intent, 0));

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.valueOf(item.getTime().substring(0, 2)));
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(item.getTime().substring(3, 5)));

alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, medication.get(i).getPi());
```

Как можно настроить его срабатывание, например, в Понедельник и Среду?

Comment: пусть срабатывает Pending Intent, например запускает сервис, а уже там можно проанализировать день недели